# Анимация перемещения transform в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Необходимо реализовать анимацию движения указателя на JS.

(без привязки к css классам анимации)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btnStart = $(".btn_start"),
      pointer = $(".bl_drum__pointer");

  btnStart.on("click", function() {
    pointer.animate({
      transform: 'translateX(-50%) translateY(-50px)'
    }, 300);
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn_start {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: background;
}

.bl_drum__full {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 37vw;
  height: 37vw;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bl_drum__pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl_drum__full">
  <div class="bl_drum__pointer">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 116.5 116" style="enable-background:new 0 0 116.5 116;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#00B51E;}
 .st1{fill:#FFDA00;}
 .st2{opacity:0.2;fill:url(#SVGID_1_);enable-background:new    ;}
</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <polygon class="st0" points="104.9,20.2 76.9,85.5 58.3,104.2 39.5,85.5 11.6,20.2 11.6,1.5 104.9,1.5   "/>
 </g>
</g>
<polygon class="st1" points="55.6,74.8 32.1,20.2 84.9,20.2 61.4,74.8 58.5,77.8 "/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="58.5" y1="651.5" x2="58.5" y2="754.2" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 -650)">
 <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
</linearGradient>
<path class="st2" d="M11.8,1.5v18.7l28,65.3l18.7,18.7l18.7-18.7l28-65.3V1.5H11.8z M100.5,19.2L73.2,82.8L58.5,97.6L43.8,82.8
 L16.5,19.2v-13h84V19.2z"/>
</svg>

  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn_start" type="button"></button>
```

Не могу понять, что я делаю не так? Почему анимация вообще не срабатывает. По идее за ***1,5 секунды*** курсор сначала поднимается вверх на `-150рх` потом спускается до `-50рх` и потом резко до `-200px`, там замирает . Можно ли это сделать на `jquery` без сторонних библиотек? Анимация происходит по нажатию на кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

1. Боюсь, что изначально к разработке подошли не правильно. SVG - это целый отдельный объект и даже отдельная страница, которую просто так не вставить в код. Попробуйте вынести весь код тега SVG, сохранить его и подключить к странице с помощью, например:

   Подробнее написано [тут](https://htmlacademy.ru/shorts/4). Внизу страницы есть интересные ссылки на более подробный материал по SVG.
2. Не весь JS доступен в SVG. Там свои обработчики.
3. Анимация в jQuery хорошо работает. Вопрос, на сколько правильно все сделать.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn_start").on("click", function() { 
    $(".bl_drum__pointer").animate({
      "left": "50px", "top": "100px"
    }, 1000);
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn_start {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: background;
}

.bl_drum__full {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 37vw;
  height: 37vw;
  z-index: 5;
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
}

.bl_drum__pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  z-index: 8;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl_drum__full">
  <div class="bl_drum__pointer">
    1
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn_start" type="button"></button>
```

Если потребуется сделать несколько действий, можете воспользоваться callback-функцией метода animate():

```
  $(".btn_start").on("click", function() { 
    $(".bl_drum__pointer").animate({
          "left": "50px",
          "top": "50px"
        }, 1000, "", function(){
        $(this).animate({
          "left": "100px",
          "top":"100px"
        }, 500)
    });
  });
```

4. Transform метод больше относится к CSS и такого метода в самом jQuery пока не встречал, скорее всего его нет. Если нужно воспользоваться методом Transform, используйте для этого метод [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn_start").on("click", function() { 
    $(".bl_drum__pointer").css({
      "-moz-transform"   : "translateX(-50%) translateY(50px)",
        "-ms-transform"    : "translateX(-50%) translateY(50px)",
       "-webkit-transform": "translateX(-50%) translateY(50px)",
        "-o-transform"    : "translateX(-50%) translateY(50px)",
      "transform"     : "translateX(-50%) translateY(50px)"
      });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn_start {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: background;
}

.bl_drum__full {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 37vw;
  height: 37vw;
  z-index: 5;
  /* border: 1px solid green; */
}

.bl_drum__pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  z-index: 8;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl_drum__full">
  <div class="bl_drum__pointer">
    1
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn_start" type="button"></button>
```